# Whats the best way to call one async function inside another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, async-await

I'm making simple authentication on React Native app using AsyncStorage to keep token. And after fetch I need to call AsyncStorage to save the token I've received. I'm looking for an advice: what is the best-practice way to do it?

```
function login(username, password) {
  const requestOptions = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    "body": JSON.stringify({ username, password })
  };
  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/authenticate`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(res => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("@Storage:key", user.token).then();//doing smth);
      return res;                    
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have to wait for `AsyncStorage.setItem("@Storage:key", user.token).then();` before returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would await with all the async requests

```
async function login(username, password) {

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    }

    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/authenticate`, requestOptions)
    const response = await response.json();
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Storage:key', user.token)
    return response.msg
}
```

Comment: you forgot the top level `async` keyword on the `login` function. and i'm assuming `const response` should be `const user`.

Comment: @RicoKahler const response could be const user if the OP intended it, I wrote what the OP mentioned in the answer and thanks for reminding me about the async keyword. I had in my mind when I started writing the answer but forgot it

Answer (score 0):

Generally, chaining Promises is one of the cleanest ways. For example, something like:

```
return fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => AsyncStorage.setItem('key', token).then(res => res.msg));
```

Pretty much how you had it.

If you can use Babel to transpile, using `async/await` can make it even nicer:

```
const res = await (await fetch(url)).json();
await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', token);
```

With `await` and `async`, as long as your `await` on a `Promise`, you can then treat them the same as non-async code.